# Как интегрировать систему API Qiwi в Unity, добавил все намертво зависает

Tags: c#, unity3d

Нашел похожее связанное с API Google: https://medium.com/@jonfoust/using-gcp-nuget-packages-with-unity-8dbd29c42cc4. Точно такая же ошибка как и у меня, что не найдена директива using. Сделал в точности, сделал все пропала ошибка, но на моменте запуска проекта просто зависает весь проект, в чем проблема не понимаю[image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
Дальше описываю что я делал когда читал похожее с API Google:

Скопировал Класс Qiwi.BillPayments.dll из папки Packages в класс Plugin.

На моменте добавления link.xml

Сделал на моменте добавления в проект link.xml может здесь что то не так, не понимаю

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<linker>
  <assembly fullname ="Qiwi">
    <type fullname ="Qiwi.BillPayments" preserve ="all"/>
  </assembly>
</linker>
```

Сохранил его в директорию с игрой:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может доступ API нужно делать в отдельном потоке: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите пожалуйста, очень хочу в этом разобраться !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообщем пошел искать в инет, перекопал просто все что можно было, до того как вопрос задал искал часов 6, после еще искал часов 5, на русскоязычном я этого не нашел, по итогу у Unity есть мануал как внедрять dll или сторонние пространства имен, что помогло мне с API QIWI, кому пригодится читайте: https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/Plugins.html.
Залайкайте пожалуйста